# Created by user period jobs Django

Tags: python, django, cron, celery

I have a small website which plots Google Calendar data for registered user. I want to add a feature: user should be able to create mailing schedule (site will generate pictures and send them on email on chosen time).

**Task:** user should be able to create/modify periodic jobs.

**Question:** what is the best way to do this?

I've checked Celery (brokers made me think it's too much for such a small project), things like [django-cron](http://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) doesn't provide jobs created by user as far as I see.

Comment: celery allows the use of the django ORM as a broker, so could be simpler than thought.

Comment: @Andee thank you, I will try it first. P.S. Only version 3.1 of Celery supports such option.

Comment: Argh I can understand why they'd drop it though it's not particularly efficient. Thanks.

Comment: I've been facing the same problem in my project, and yes, celery is a right tool for it. To solve this you just need to think another way - don't create/modify jobs in  _celery_, but create a task, that is invoked like every 5 sec and that checks what mails needed to be sent.

Comment: @Fian Thank you for advice, and how do you store the information "*what mails needed to be sent*"? I'm looking at django-celery-beat and my idea is just to create PeriodicTask for every user.

Comment: Django-celery-beat don't support dynamic task change, so you have to restart your celery-beat process after every job change. In my project I evaluate so called "next time for a task to be invoked" and check it every 5 sec like BackgroundTasks.objects.Filter(next_invoke_time_lte=datetime.now()).